# CouchDB run a list function on _changes

Tags: javascript, couchdb

I need to create a feed based on changed documents. I figured the _changes api would be perfect in this case. Ie simply store the last sequence id client side, so we can use it to limit the results in the next call to _changes.

Currently, the application performs the following:

- calls _changes with since/filter parameters
- calls a show function for each id in the _changes feed
- renders all changes into the customer feed

What I would like, is to be able to call a list function on the entire _changes result in a single request. This would remove the need to explicitly parse the _changes result on the client, and move that functionality to the server.

The question: is this even remotely possible?

I have been trying to implement a view, doing "almost" the same thing as _changes, but without any real luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible at the time, and the `_changes` API is different enough from regular views that it's not entirely straightforward to implement.

There is a [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-979) open in the CouchDB issue tracker, but it hasn't been updated in quite a while.